# charAt first letter of last word in a string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to select the first letter of the last word in a string: such as the first letter after the last space.

"Hello World"
I need to select "W"
"Hello World I am young"
need to select "y"

using charAt()

thanks

Comment: You probably need more than just `charAt`. Or are you expected to do this with only looping?

Answer (score 5):

You can split string by empty space, pop last element and ask for it's first letter:

```
"Hello World".split(" ").pop().charAt(0); // W
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `lastIndexOf` function:

```
var str = "Hello World";
str.charAt(str.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A string is just an array of characters, so you can access it with square brackets. In order to get the first letter of each word in your string, try this:

```
var myString = "Hello World"
var myWords = myString.split(" ");
myWords.forEach(function(word) {
    console.log(word[0]);
});
```

For just the last word in a string:

```
var myString = "Hello World"
var myWords = myString.split(" ");
console.log(myWords[myWords.length-1][0]);
```

Comment: You meant `myWords.length-1`?

Comment: I did! That's what I get for rushing. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just allowed to use charAt do the following:

Iterate through the whole string and always remember the last position you have found an empty space. If you are at the end of the string take the char next to the position you have remembered for the last empty space you have found.

Be aware of the case that your string ends with an empty space. If this could be the case you will probably need two indexes. Also take care if your string does not contain any empty space.